# Running in Test using XUnit

Tags: c#, xunit

Trying to learn Test Driven Design for the first time. I have a server that goes like this:

```
public class ServerEngine
    {
        private static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        private static List<Socket> _clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];

        public ServerEngine()
        {
            SetupServer();
        }

        private void SetupServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up the server...");
            _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 100));

            // Settingup the backlog
            _serverSocket.Listen(1);

            //Listen for connections
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }

        private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Add the accepted socket to the list of sockets
            Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(ar);
            _clientSockets.Add(socket);
            Console.WriteLine("A client has connected");
            // listen for messages coming from the new accepted socket
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
            // Start accepting a new connection again
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }

        private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                var received = socket.EndReceive(ar);
                var dataBuf = new byte[received];
                Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received);

                var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
                Console.WriteLine($"Text Received: {text}");

                var response = AddToHashSet(text);
                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response.ToString());
                socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
                socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
                _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                socket.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("A client has disconnected.");
            }
        }

        private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            socket.EndSend(ar);
        }

        private HashSet<TidContainerModel> _tidContainerModels = new HashSet<TidContainerModel>(new TidContainerModelComparer());
        private bool AddToHashSet(string value)
        {
            var tcv = new TidContainerModel
            {
                Tid = value,
                TimeAdded = DateTime.Now,
                Type = 'R',
                Rssi = -444
            };
            return _tidContainerModels.Add(tcv);
        }
    }
```

This I call in the Program Main to setup the server. Then I created an xUnit test like so:

```
private Socket _clentSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        private ServerEngine serverEngine = new ServerEngine();

        [Fact]
        public void ConnectToServerTest()
        {
            // Arrange
            bool expected = true;

            // Act
            bool actual = LoopConnect();

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }

        private bool LoopConnect()
        {
            int attempts = 0;
            var connected = false;
            while (!_clentSocket.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    attempts++;
                    var ipAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.35.71"), 100);
                    _clentSocket.Connect(ipAddress);
                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed connecting {se.Message}. Reconnecting attempt {attempts}");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }

            connected = true;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to the server");
            return connected;
        }
```

Without using the Test this program runs fine. But when I use the test, I fail with an error of:

```
Server.Test.ServerEngineTest.ConnectToServerTest
   Source: ServerEngineTest.cs line 15
   Duration: 209 ms

  Message: 
System.IO.IOException : The handle is invalid.


  Stack Trace: 
__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
Console.GetBufferInfo(Boolean throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded)
Console.Clear()
ServerEngineTest.LoopConnect() line 51
ServerEngineTest.ConnectToServerTest() line 21
```

[image]

If I use a console application to connect to the server, it works perfect. I want to learn how to use the xUnit with this project.

Comment: Do you try to connect the outside server in UT? UT should not depend on external resources, if you need access to external resources, you can mock them.

Comment: I am just doing this in my local machine. I am really new to Testing. I just started today actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your stack trace, it's telling you the problem:

```
  Stack Trace: 
__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
Console.GetBufferInfo(Boolean throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded)
Console.Clear()
ServerEngineTest.LoopConnect() line 51
ServerEngineTest.ConnectToServerTest() line 21
```

Basically, you're trying to clear the console, but you have no console allocated in your test. Which is something you should never do for two reasons:

1. You should be mocking your I/O to be able to test it.
2. You should absolutely never mix this kind of console I/O with your socket service, whatever it does. Use dependency injection to extract and contain console I/O (or even better, a proper logging interface) separate from the actual work of starting and maintaining a TCP server.

Comment: Oh I see. You are totally right with the DI. This is a low .net Framework project so I didn't use the DI to make things a lot simple coz I want to focus more on the Testing part coz I really don't know anything about it, yet. But this really did it. Thank you.